# HTTP None None for url <https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-64/repodata.json.bz2>

Tags: python, windows, anaconda

I am trying to do a

> conda update conda

C:\Users****>conda update conda
Fetching package metadata ...
CondaHTTPError: HTTP None None for url https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-64/repodata.json.bz2
Elapsed: None

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.
ConnectTimeout(MaxRetryError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='repo.continuum.io', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pkgs/free/win-64/repodata.json.bz2 (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(, 'Connection to repo.continuum.io timed out. (connect timeout=9.15)'))",),)

my conda info is:

Current conda install:

```
           platform : win-64
      conda version : 4.3.21
   conda is private : False
  conda-env version : 4.3.21
conda-build version : not installed
     python version : 3.6.1.final.0
   requests version : 2.14.2
   root environment : C:\Users\****\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3  (writable)
default environment : C:\Users\****\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3
   envs directories : C:\Users\****\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs
                      C:\Users\****\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
                      C:\Users\****\.conda\envs
      package cache : C:\Users\****\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\pkgs
                      C:\Users\****\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       channel URLs : https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-64
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/win-64
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/noarch
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/win-64
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/msys2/noarch
        config file : C:\Users\DantuJ\.condarc
         netrc file : None
       offline mode : False
         user-agent : conda/4.3.21 requests/2.14.2 CPython/3.6.1 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.15063
      administrator : False
```

my .condarc file is:

**channels:
  - defaults

ssl_verify: false**

How can I fix this issue so that I can use conda to download other packages or even update conda?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The diagnostic messages seem to suggest that you should try to do `conda update conda` once again. Did you do that?

Comment: Since you are new to SO you may not know that to reply to an individual here you should enter the 'at' symbol for a menu of recipients.

Comment: @BillBell yes I have tried doing a conda update conda again. I am getting CondaHTTPError: HTTP None None for url <https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-64/repodata.json.bz2> as an error

Comment: @JishnuDantu did you get it solved? I am having the same issue!

Comment: Hi @DiegoFMedina, Sorry for the late reply. My company's IT dept had to put the url in the acceptable url list for the command to work for me.